# SQL For Mere Mortals

Tags: sql

I have recently bought SQL Queries for Mere Mortals book. Can I get an advise how to load script from this book to existing Oracle's database? I'm newbie in this so I  really need help.

Comment: If you try writing the scripts by yourself, you will learn it better. Learn by doing. Goodluck!

Comment: Scripts are typically run using `sqlplus`